# How does jest mock the module a dependency requires?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I know how to mock a module through `jest` in my unit tests. But my problem is that how I can mock a module which is required by a dependency. For example, I have dependency `A` defined in my `package.json` file while `A` dependents on `B`. So in my unit tests how I can mock `B` which is used by `A`?

Answer (score 1):

[`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) works well for any-level dependency. So

```
jet.mock('B');
```

at the start of test for `A` will work.

Also you can [provide auto-mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) by placing mocks into special folder named `__mocks__`. So once `B` is in `node_modules` we need to have mock in sibling `__mocks__` directory next to `node_modules` like

```
 -   node_modules
 --  B
 --- index.js
 -   __mocks__
 --  B.js
```

And finally beware of

> Warning: If we want to mock Node's core modules (e.g.: fs or path), then explicitly calling e.g. jest.mock('path') is required, because core Node modules are not mocked by default.